# Объясните как связать таблицы

Tags: python, django

Делаю сайт на джанго. Cамый первый опыт.Не обучен азам. Тыкаюсь во все подряд так сказать. У меня есть дефолтная таблица предметов с указанием на их количество имеющихся в наличии(соответственно 0 изначально), и количество нужное для завершения квеста. Хочу чтобы для каждого пользователя эта таблица была как дефолт, и он сам уже смог добавлять имеющиеся предметы или же убавлять их. Как мне её разделить для каждого пользователя? К каждому пользователю создавать отдельно новую таблицу из дефолта при создании юзера, или как?

Answer (score 0):

На слух кажется, что в models.py вам нужно описать две модели. Условно class Items куда сложить предметы и сделать ее поля модели models.IntegerField (default = 0) и class Users, где описать models.ForeignKey на позиции Items, ну и данные по пользователю, которые вы задумали.

Тогда для каждого пользователя будет заводится новый объекта класса Users и ему будут соответствовать его Items. В будущем сможете отслеживать как совокупное кол-во предметов, так и по каждому конкретному.

Так же рекомендую посмотреть ролики на YouTube как работать с django, особенно если только начали. Там описаны азы, а докручивать уже будете читая документацию